# how to not save an inputted data to dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I'm still a student and I'm currently working on a project about a mini student record system. Like an enrollment system. Now there's a part where I ask if the user wants to save the inputted subject. If yes then it will be saved but if not, how will I stop the computer on saving the inputted subject?

```
save = input('Save Record?(yes/no): ')
if save =='y' or save == 'yes':
    print('Subject successfully added.')
    print("Subject\t\tUnits")
else:
```

Comment: What? You put the code that saves the input into the `if` block, and don't put the same code into the `else` block.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "stop the computer on saving the inputted subject" ? Maybe you can edit your question to add the code you use to save ?

Comment: In if condition, you have not called any method to save subject or coded. you are just printing the the subject is added successfully. If there is a method for saving subject. Just do not use it in else block and it will not add.

Comment: well the user will input a subject then next asks the user to input the units per subject.. after that i wrote a program that will ask the user if he wants to save the subject inputted.. i wonder what should i do if the user will answer "no". the subject is the key to the dictionary and the units are the values